# Update event not working

Tags: vba, excel

I'll make this one as direct as possible.
Three work sheets in play.  Notes, shGather and Delay Report.  As the Notes worksheet is updated, it finds flights that are delayed and automatically loads them to the shGather sheet.  This functionality is working just fine.  My question is in regards to the update event of the shGather worksheet.

I have the following code on the shGather worksheet.  The intent is to run the array any time the sheet updates.  The information on the shGather, if appropriate, then populates the Delay report.

```
Sub wsGather_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim wsg As Worksheet
Dim wsd As Worksheet
Dim a As Long  'Total Array
'Dim b As Long
Dim i As Long  'Rows
Dim j As Long  'Columns
Dim lr As Long  'lr is shorthand for last row in the count
Dim cr As Long  'cr is shorthand for current row
Dim cc As Long  'cc is shorthand for current column
Dim arval As String  'array values
Dim aval As Variant  'A column on the shGather worksheet.  This value will determine if the information is added to the array
Dim array1()

If Not Intersect(Target, wsg.Range("A2:A15")) Is Nothing Then

Set wsg = Worksheets("Gather")  'Add data from this worksheet to the array
Set wsd = Worksheets("Delay Report") 'deposit information from the array to this worksheet

lr = wsg.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

arval = "" 'This will be the total strig value of the individual array values that are captured
a = 0  'counts the total number of rows of data that exist in the array

    For i = 2 To lr  'Start the array
        aval = wsg.Range("A" & i).Value

        If aval = "Y" Then  'Set the search parameters
            arval = wsg.Range("B" & i).Value & "~#pop#~"  'Start collecting data with the B column

                For j = 7 To 14
                    arval = arval & wsg.Cells(i, j).Value & "~#pop#~"   'continue collecting information in the various columns
                Next j
            ReDim Preserve array1(a)
            array1(a) = arval
            a = a + 1
        End If

    Next i

wsd.Range("G2:O15").ClearContents  'Clears the inserts range

If a > 0 Then
    cr = 2
    For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)
        cc = 6
        newarr = Split(array1(i), "`#pop#~")
        For j = LBound(newarr) To UBound(newarr)
            wsd.Cells(cr, cc).Value = newarr(j)
            cc = cc + 1
        Next j
        cr = cr + 1
    Next i
End If

End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True





End Sub
```

I can't seem to figure out why I'm not getting array output results to the Delay Report.  I'm not even sure that the code is firing on the correct event which is what I suspect.  The shGather sheet has no direct inputs from any user.  It just collects data.

I suspect either I have the wrong event, or there is something else wrong with my code.  Any insights would be helpful.

I have taken a great deal of time trying to understand this, I'm closer but still learning.  At least this time I have code to display.

Comment: To test if the code is firing, put a breakpoint on the first line, and see if the routine gets called. Also, you're turning all those application events to TRUE at the end, but they aren't being set to FALSE at the start. So they don't do anything.

Comment: The event is typically `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.  If you're referring the the sheet itself from the sheet's code module then it's safer to use `Me` in place of (eg) `Worksheets("Gather")`

Answer (score 2):

See Tim's comment re why it isn't firing. That said, I don't believe your code is going to do what you want anyway. For instance, your line `If Not Intersect(Target, wsg.Range("A2:A15")) Is Nothing Then` will always equal nothing, because wsg hasn't been set to anything when it is called.

Also, I take it you have some kind of worksheet_change event on the Notes sheet that populates the Gather sheet, and then this event is supposed to kick in and do something else? If so, just move the "doing stuff" bit of this code to that other event handler...doesn't make sense to have two event handlers on different sheets responding to one thing the user does.

Comment: I took your advice and moved the code to a Command button and it seems to be working well.  My only remaining problem is the spacing.  Some of the information has to skip a column but I haven't quite figured out how to do that just yet.